# consider base as product, assign values as 1 until the value product repeat again. if the product repeat again increase the count

Tags: sql, repeat, partition

Write a Sql query to get the expected output
Input:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Product |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| Product |
| z |
| y |
| x |
| Product |
| ABC |

| Column A | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Product | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| Product | 2 |
| z | 2 |
| y | 2 |
| x | 2 |
| Product | 3 |
| ABC | 3 |

select *, row_number() over(partition by ColumnA order by ColumnA asc) from Table

Comment: There is nothing in your table setting apart rows with ColumnA='Product' from each other. You seem to be relying on the display order of them as you pasted them, but that would mean nothing to SQL. Do you have another columns you don't show us helping you order the rows in this manner?